# What is the meaning of "All is for the best in the best of all possible worlds"

Tags: quotes

Could you please explain this sentence to me? It is from Voltaire’s Candide.

Comment: Perhaps Voltaire wrote it in French?  Maybe you should ask for the meaning of the French version...

Comment: I am a English learner and I actually encountered this sentence in the TIME...

Comment: It sounds like a tautology to me.

Comment: Perhaps do some of your own research.  Look for that phrase on the Internet.

Comment: Wikipedia has fairly detailed discussion of [best of all possible worlds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_of_all_possible_worlds).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I just want to say that I did some home work using Google and the Wikipedia before asking this question, but I failed. The accepted answer, on the other hand, helps me understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some background.

Leibniz was a philosopher, and an optimistic fellow. He thought that the way the world was arranged was in the best way that it could possibly be.

He didn't think that there weren't bad things in it, but that you couldn't do any better: if you fixed something, you'd just make even more stuff worse. He thought that the world was at least the "best of a bad job" and any even slight utopia would be impossible.

So, of all the **possible** worlds, this was the **best** one. All those improvements you can imagine? Either not possible, or not improvements. God sits there tweaking dials until the world is most excellent. Sorry about the bad bits, you can't get the parts these days, no chance. Our world is **"the best of all *possible* worlds"**.

If you really believe that the world is like that, then when some terrible event happens (like a volcano erupting, say), you might think, well **"everything is for the best"**, meaning that the event might seem terrible, but as we live in the best of all possible worlds (you believe), then the volcano was the best that we could reasonably hope for.

Someone who agrees with Leibniz might have argued, -- I dunno -- that if the volcano hadn't erupted, then the pressure would have built up and the earth exploded and everyone on the planet die. You might not know in what way something bad was for the best (you're not God, after all), but you're still convinced that it was **"for the best"**, it was the best that could be done.

You probably think this because you believe God is nice. (Leibniz ended up in this funny position because he was thinking about the old "why do bad things happen to good people" question).

So not only puppies and rainbows, but volcanoes and syphilis, all of these things -- **everything** -- is the best that could be done, ie it is **for the best**. Why is **everything for the best?** because this is **the best of all possible worlds**.

Now some folk, including Voltaire, weren't quite so optimistic, and thought that they saw far too much evil which all seemed so unnecessary, and thought Leibniz was maybe a little bit ignorant of daily life for many people. (In particular, Voltaire knew about a terrible earthquake, fire, and tsunami in Portugal and various stupid, nasty imperial wars).

Voltaire wrote a famous short novel, *Candide*, where a chap first of all goes along with Leibniz's notion, under the influence of his mentor (Dr Pangloss) but then, through a series of unlikely adventures, discovers the misery of the world, and ends up rejecting it.

Candide was very controversial at the time because Leibniz was greatly respected, and Voltaire also took the opportunity to poke fun at just about everyone else in positions of power at the same time, secular and religious. So the novel became, and still is, very famous.

So someone saying **"everything is for the best in the best of all possible worlds"** is now associated principally with the satire, and so is almost never used sincerely. It is used to describe this kind of complacent self-assurance that apparent injustice or other evil could not be avoided or was somehow necessary in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: This is the best in the best of all possible answers. Thank you so much!